# Displaying fees within the reports of woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce with another plugin called "Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce".

When the user is in the process of checking out they can add a tip. I have two tip options for different people within the business. Both tip options have the option of 0%, 10%, 15%, 20%...

The plugin displays those tips as "Fee" in the total after checking out.

I would like to know how this "Fee" can show up in the reports option within Woocommerce.

Thank you for any info.

I tryed a few report plugins but none have itemized the fees.